# Cost of thread switching in RxJava and Kotlin data class copy() operation

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, kotlin, rx-java2

My question is about costs of operations in particular the cost of **Kotlin** *data class* `copy()` operation and **RxJava** `observeOn()` thread switching.

I have a system which produces events on let's say `Schedulers.mainThread`. The events are **Kotlin** *data classes*. Next there is the business logic and in the end, the chain produces new *data class* by `copy()` operation. All results have to be consumed on `Schedulers.mainThread`. So, a chain would look like that:

```
eventSource() //Events are produced on Schedulers.mainThread
.observeOn(Schedulers.computation)
.map { event ->
    other business logic
    event.copy(...)
}
.observeOn(Schedulers.mainThread)
.subscribe(eventConsumer)
```

Thereby, the question is it worth to switch schedulers by `observeOn` for such operation as `copy()` if event class has let's say 15 fields. It should be mentioned that `Schedulers.mainThread` is thread used to render UI and is better to be as vacant as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`copy` just calls the data class constructor with default arguments for those you haven't passed, i.e.

```
event.copy(field3 = "")
```

is the same as

```
Event(event.field1, event.field2, "", event.field4, ...)
```

By itself it is very unlikely to be worth switching schedulers, but of course "other business logic" may well be, and if you have

```
event.copy(field3 = complexCalculation())
```

you need to consider the costs of `complexCalculation()`.